# ansible conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters

Tags: ansible

What I can use to replace {{ }} while I still want to use variables?

```
when: ansible_lvm.lvs.{{ resize_lvname }}.size_g < 10 and
      ansible_devices.{{ new_dev }}.size == "70.00 GB
```

> [WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
> delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: ansible_lvm.lvs.{{
> resize_lvname }}.size_g < 10 and ansible_devices.{{ new_dev }}.size ==
> "70.00 GB" and not "[new_dev].value.partitions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `when` conditional you are already inside an implicit Jinja template context...which means if you want to refer to a variable, you just need the variable name.  For example:

```
when: ansible_lvm.lvs[resize_lvname].size_g < 10 and
      ansible_devices[new_dev].size == "70.00 GB
```

Recall that `some.var.key` is equivalent to `some.var["key"]`; we need to use the `[...]` syntax here because we want to use the *value* of `resize_lvname` as key on the `ansible_lvm.lvs` dictionary.  If we were to write `ansible_lvm.lvs.resize_lvname`, we would be attempting to look up a key with the literal name `resize_lvmname` (in other words, that would be equivalent to `ansible_lvm.lvs["resize_lvname"]`).

Comment: I saw the suggestion on another post and already tried it, it didn't work. For example, if I try the first line only for a test, it fails with this error.

Comment: fatal: [linux1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_lvm.lvs.[resize_lvname].size_g < 10' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {% if ansible_lvm.lvs.[resize_lvname].size_g < 10 %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/jerry/roles/jenkins/tasks/main.yml': line 20, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: LVM tasks for RHEL 6 and 7\n  ^ here\n"}

Comment: There was a typo in the post. Sorry about that.